# SQL Server problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

when right click on any database (when i am connected) and select "script database as" and try to select any options(eg. to create). i get (Discover dependencies failed, microsoft.sqlserver.smo) error. i was able to do it a while ago and could not figure out what went wrong. please help me out.

Comment: Are you using SSMS? What version of SQL Server? What version of SSMS?

Comment: i am using ssms. thats sql server 2008. thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Repair sqlserver using its utility(Installer)...

or if you already have created other login to your
server try to use it and if error occurs again i think...try to  re-install it again.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Simply restarting the SQL Server service fixed this problem for me.